# How to use QCommandLineParser for arguments list?

Tags: c++, qt

How to use `QCommandLineParser` to give a list of values for one argument? I would like to make this kind of program execution:

```
./exec -opt 1 2 3
```

Note that doing the following (as in [How to use QCommandLineParser for arguments with multiple params?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590362/how-to-use-qcommandlineparser-for-arguments-with-multiple-params)) is not the goal:

```
./exec -opt 1 -opt 2 -opt 3
```

Comment: Maybe you are trying to stuff a square peg into a round hole. Aka using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Of course, but I am working on a big project that uses qt. So I am trying to use this tool only, even for such easy job. I am surprised that qt does not provide this feature...